# Obtain index of the smallest number in a file

Tags: bash, shell, file, indexing, minimum

There is an input file 'data.txt' that contains the following numbers

```
11.0    22.0    33.0    -10.5    -2
```

How to find the value and index of the smallest number in the file. In that case the output will be

```
Value -10.5
Index 4
```

Comment: please add some code to read and write file

Comment: I am not sure if cat is the right command to use to read numbers from a text file

Comment: Could you please show us `input file` and `expected output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it to multiple lines using `grep`, attach line number (index) using `cat -n` and then `sort` on the value. For smallest number, choose the first record (`head -1`)

```
# here is the file...
$ cat data.txt
11.0 22.0 33.0 0.5 44.0

# here is the output you want
$ grep -o '[^ ]\+' data.txt | cat -n | sort -g --key=2 | head -1
 4  0.5
```

If you want the values in separate variables

```
# store the value in a variable
$ res=`grep -o '[^ ]\+' data.txt | cat -n | sort -g --key=2 | head -1 | xargs`

# then cut out the data
$ index=`echo $res | cut -f1 -d' '`
$ value=`echo $res | cut -f2 -d' '`

$ echo $index
 4
$ echo $value
 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i make the outputs two variables idxex=4 and value=0.5 so that I can pass these two variables to other parts of the code?

Comment: Updated the answer, see above.

Comment: Thanks for  annotating your code. This code does not work for negative numbers.  For example if the file contains -10.5 that should be selected as the smallest number. I modified the question accordingly. To work for negative numbers I guess you nee to do sort -r --key=2. Could you please revise your answer accordingly.

Comment: Please correct the code by revising "sort -r" to "sort -g" to sort according to general numerical value.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> cat data.txt
11.0    22.0    33.0    0.5    44.0
> perl -lane ' {@arr=sort @F;foreach(@F) { $x++;  print "$x $_" if $arr[0]==$_ } }' data.txt
4 0.5
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i make the outputs two variables index=4 and value=-10.5 so that I can pass these two variables to other parts of the code? I also modified the question to include negative numbers. Please revise your solution accordingly because this code will not work correctly for negative numbers.